# Convert specific string format to Sql server 2012 datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm getting date as string from Java output as: **Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016**

I would like to manually avoid typing "2016-04-2..etc" in my datetime field in my table during debug, and also avoid to create manual method for formating that date.

Instead, I would like to do this on the fly on database. I would like to convert given string format to date. I have tried many examples, but I couldn't solve it. Most close I found was this:

```
select convert(datetime, 'Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016', 127) from mytable
```

**I need this in SQL Server 2012.** Seems due to documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), it can parse may formats, but it can't parse this kind of string I noticed.

**Anybody knows how to convert this given string to date?**

Answer (score 3):

Please try this below query:

```
 select cast(substring(replace ('Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016','CEST','') ,4,len(replace ('Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016','CEST',''))) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 select convert(datetime, REPLACE((SUBSTRING('Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016', PATINDEX('%CEST%', 'Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016')+5, 4)
 + ' ' + SUBSTRING('Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016', 5, (PATINDEX('%CEST%', 'Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016')-5))),'CEST',''), 109)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the format is fixed, this query should work

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE(SUBSTRING('Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016',4, LEN('Wed Apr 27 09:56:56 CEST 2016')-3),'CEST','')) from mytable
```